# translate with angular does not work with useStaticFilesLoader

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-translate

I want to use translation with angular and I followed this tutorial :
http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-translate.html

I load those two files:

```
<script src="js/angular/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js"></script>
```

**html**

```
{{ 'SORTBY' | translate }}
```

When I do the follow, translation works :

```
$translateProvider.translations('en', {
                SORTBY: 'sort by'
              })
              .translations('fr', {
                SORTBY: 'trier par'
              });
```

Now I want to do this :

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
                prefix: '/languages/',
                suffix: '.json'
            });
```

I do well load the files as my console network shows me the GET success with the right content which is :

**en.json**

```
SORTBY: "Sort by"
```

**fr.json**

```
SORTBY: "Trier par"
```

It shows :

SORTBY

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was all because of the Jsons writting.
This syntax solved my problem :

```
{
    "SORTBY": "Sort by"
}
```

Comment: This works. But also be aware of trailing commas! You must have a well written json in order to make this work. Otherwise it will fail silently.

Answer (score -1):

The prefix attribute is the prefix of the file, not the location therefore it is looking for a file called languages/'someValue'.json. This worked in a previous project of mine, therefore you can try to rename your files to locale-en.json and locale-fr.json.

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
          prefix: 'locale-',
          suffix: '.json'
        });
```

Comment: Please consider the information given in my question :
`I do well load the files as my console network chose me the GET success with the right content `
That is not true, prefix does contain the path to the file.
You can see demo in the ex7 here : https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/tree/master/demo

Answer (score -1):

I had very similar issue before few minutes and the problem was in usage of `'` inestead of `"` in JSON file:

BAD

```
{
    'SORTBY': 'Sort by'
}
```

GOOD

```
{
    "SORTBY": "Sort by"
}
```

It has solved my problem, maybe can help to someone.